# Null pointer exception thrown in Autowired service class when I used JWT Authentication

Tags: java, spring-boot, jwt

I am creating the jwt authentication for a different role than here showing a null pointer exception. but when this URL I paste on the web security configuration class with the antmatcher method the API works fine but it shows an error in pre-authorize when I used it.

## **This is the Controller class**

[Controller Class Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9oDOX.png)

```
package com.shashank.controller;
.........
@RestController
@CrossOrigin
public class StudentController {
    @Autowired
    StudentService studentService;

        @GetMapping("/api/student/stu")
        @PreAuthorize("hasRole('User')")
        private List<Student> getAllUStudent(){
            System.out.println("Get Call");
            return studentService.getAllStudent();
        }
```

## **This is the Error in console**

[Error showing in Postman](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j253u.png)

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "com.shashank.service.StudentService.getAllStudent()" because "this.studentService" is null
    at com.shashank.controller.StudentController.getAllUStudent(StudentController.java:28) ~[classes/:na]
```

Answer (score -1):

Are you annotating your service class?
Spring uses component scanning to find the classes that it needs to auto-wire and insert into classes for IoC. Basically, Spring is going to scan the project's classpath (or paths you specified), find all of the @Component classes and make them available for auto-wiring. So if you forget to annotate a class it will not be auto-wired and when you try and use it you will get a null and a NullPointerException.

@Service, @Repository and @Controller are all specializations of @Component, so any class you want to auto-wire needs to be annotated with one of them.

Comment: Spring, by default, will not let an `@Autowired` field remain un-injected. If it can't find an appropriate bean, it will throw an exception and fail initialization.